# Set audio source

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, audio

I have a .wav file in my project and I would like to use it to play on my website. I can't directly use my local .wav's path. Any ideas? I am using Spring mvc 4.0, jetty.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<audio id="audio" src="TODO!" autostart="false" ></audio>

<button value="Work work!" onclick="PlaySound()"/>

<script>
    function PlaySound() {
        var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
        sound.play()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why you can't directly use local .wav's path?

Comment: @AlexFilatov It doesnt work and chrome tools (F12) tells me 'Not allowed to load local recource'

Comment: in this case perhaps you should put you .wav file to share service with ```https``` allowed and use url from there service. For example, dropbox.com